# Shortcut item on app icon not working with iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

To support shortcut items on the app icon we've implemented the following method in `SceneDelegate`:

```
func windowScene(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
```

This method does not get called when the app is killed and launched through such an shortcut item (it just shows the main screen). However when the app is running and in the background this method gets called and everything works as expected.

I've also checked `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to see whether there's a shortcut item in `launchingOptions` but they are `nil`.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. I vaguely recall seeing some statement about state not being restored on launch after an app is force-quit. Some sort of safety mechanism. This may be related. I'll see if I can find that statement.

Comment: same problem for me

Answer (score 3):

Check for shortcutItem in

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

    if let shortcutItem = connectionOptions.shortcutItem {
        shortcutItemToProcess = shortcutItem
    }
}
```

and then handle it in

```
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    if let shortcutItem = shortcutItemToProcess {
        shortcutItemToProcess = nil
    }
}
```