# Issues with IOS Universal link launch

Tags: ios, uikit, ios-universal-links, uiscenedelegate

I have followed this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app) to set up Universal links. I think I've set up everything successfully because when I tap a universal link, my app is launching and I'm receiving the URL in [scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3197914-scene), as shown below:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        
    Log("SceneDelegate.scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)")
        
    let userActivities: Set<NSUserActivity> = connectionOptions.userActivities
        
    for userActivity in userActivities {
            
        guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
            let universalLink = userActivity.webpageURL else {
            Log("Not launched via universal links!")
            return
        }
            
        Log(String(format: "userActivities = %@", String(describing: userActivity)))
        Log(String(format: "universalLink = %@", universalLink.absoluteString))

        // Update UI
    }
}
```

But when my app is running in background and a universal link is used, my app comes to the foreground, but link is not delivered as a `NSUserActivity` object to [scene(_:continue:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenedelegate/3238056-scene) as [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app#Update-your-app-delegate-to-respond-to-a-universal-link).

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        
        Log("SceneDelegate.scene(_:continue:)")
        
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let universalLink = userActivity.webpageURL else {
        Log("Not launched via universal links!")
        return
    }
        
    Log(String(format: "userActivities = %@", String(describing: userActivity)))
    Log(String(format: "universalLink = %@", universalLink.absoluteString))
        
    // Update UI
}
```

The above method doesn't get invoked and UI doesn't get updated.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70536109/12791298) also confirms my understanding but I didn't get the URL. What is missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a TSI to AppleDTS and they informed me that the scene(_:continue:) method is for a UIKit app. For SwiftUI app, we have to use the [onOpenURL(_:perform:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onopenurl(perform:)) view modifier to handle universal links (and other URL based launches like file launch, deep link etc.) as shown below.

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .onOpenURL(perform: { (universalLink: URL) in
                    
            Log(String(format: "universalLink = %@", universalLink.absoluteString))
             
            // Handle universal link 
        })
}
```